# BGE: Can a rigged rigid body interact with BGE physics?

Tags: game-engine, physics, rigid-body-simulation

BGE: Can a rigged rigid body interact with BGE physics?

Basically, I want to know if it is possible to have a mesh that is animated by an armature interact with the BGE physics, including other rigidbodies.

[Question blend file.](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32723)

Comment: Are you sure? My experiences has been that armature deformed mesh only detects collision on the original mesh, not the deformed one. (Turning on physics visualization confirms this).

Comment: Right, basically deformation is not supported in the physics engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An armature rigged mesh cannot interact with other rigidbody objects, as the mesh deformation by the bones are not sent to the physics engine. (They are actually done on the GPU as of Blender 2.71 [[source]](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Game_Engine))

Your only option is to parent a bunch of collision proxies to the armature and use those instead of the actual rigged mesh, [like this](http://cgcookie.com/blender/lessons/1-game-engine-simple-character/).

Answer (score 0):

[Why not try collision sectors?](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/588949035289673738/667085288450949140/stack_overflow_answer_charactar_physics.blend)

with a simpler armature like a character you can place collision bounds automatically to each limb. (manually assuming the size of the collision bound you need). and use integrals or for loops to get measures between Bone.pose_head & Bone.pose_tail for higher quality collisions to your charactar mesh.

I already attempted this in my example, and must apologize for the mess as I was not able to accomplish it, but it is absolutely possible, if you want to give it a go I left my old code in.

as for mapping a convex hull or tri mesh collision to the charactar armature, this may or may not be possible (i'm not really sure.) The problem is that you cannot get the vertexes in their moved positions from the armature that I am aware of, if you could, then you could make a seperate but equal and equivelant mesh of the character and map every vert from the collision mesh to the player mesh leaving the player mesh with no collisions and accomplish a very high quality goal. but more slowly.

my .blend above however won't work on everything, if the bones potrude from the inside of the mesh then it won't be possible for you to build this physics type using these collision sectors.